# Angular every console.log comes from mainjs:1 in dev

Tags: angular, build, config, environment, development-environment

when starting my application with `ng serve` (now `ng serve -- -c deploy`, because of testing, every console.log comes from either `main.js:1` or `polyfills.js:1`, independet from which component I call the console.log().

In an other stackoverflow ([Angular console logs only from main.js:1 and polyfills.js:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68100607/angular-console-logs-only-from-main-js1-and-polyfills-js1)) someone wrote that this appears because angular doesnt build dev and instead buils production.

Here is my angular.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "project": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/project",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss",
                            "src/custom-theme.scss",
                            "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
                            "src/css/md-theme/theme.css",
                            "primeng/resources/themes/md-dark-indigo/theme.css",
                            "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
                            "./node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "./node_modules/libsignal-protocol/dist/libsignal-protocol.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                                    "maximumError": "10kb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "project:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "project:build:production"
                        },
                        "deploy": {
                            "browserTarget": "project:build"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "project:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "project:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "project:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "project"
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is true that is build angular build prod by default. Although, I am  not so sure why you want to see logs from different components, you can configure your angular.json to serve on dev mode, then you will be able to see the logs from each component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the newer versions of Angular, it by default is served in `prod` mode. You can create a `dev` setting under `configurations` after the `production` setting in your `angular.json`.

```
    "dev": {
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": false,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true,
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
          }
        ]}
```

And then try running your serve command as `ng serve -c dev`

Comment: For people that see this in the future. You also have to create a file `environment.dev.ts` in the environments folder and you also have to create a new configuration underneeth serve which has the browserTarge `"[your-project-name]:build:dev"`

Answer (score 0):

If you tried out everything `dev` vs `prod environment` related stuff and still doesn't wok:
 as @jna said [in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706179/16109231), enabling JS source maps in chrome devTools could help.

Also: Open devTools, press `F1` than check  **Enable JavaScript source map** option.