# Angular 13 ng serve -> console.log() does not display proper filenames

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular13, angular-config

If I create a new Angular 13 project with `$ ng new my-test-app` and add

```js
constructor() {
  console.log('Hello there');
}
```

to **app.component.ts**, then do `$ ng serve` and open the browser..
"*Hello there*" is logged in the console, but it says it's coming from **main.js** instead of **app.component.ts**

Is this expected behavior? And does anyone know how to change it?

---

**angular.json** snippet below

```json
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-testy-app-2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-testy-app-2:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-testy-app-2:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
    ....
```

---

**Edit:** Seems like the issue is with my chrome browser. It displays the files correctly in the firefox console. Will add a solution when I figure out why

Comment: Does this happen in an incognito tab of Chrome? What version of the browser are you using?

Comment: Yup. Also in incognito. I'm running Chrome Version 100.0.4896.60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"Enable Javascript source maps"*** was not enabled in my Chrome Dev Tools Settings (F1).
Enabling it solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you @jna !
After 1 hour of messing with dev vs prod config found your response and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

this isn't the default behavior expected from a fresh project generated with the cli, somehow source maps got turned off in your build configuration... in angular.json, under projects.[your-project].architect.build.configurations.development set

```
"sourceMap": true
```

this assumes your angular.json has a development build config and the `ng serve` command runs with the development build as it's target, which may not be the case, as again, your configuration file is for some reason non standard.  If this doesn't work, may need to see the angular.json file to fix it.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but "sourceMap" was already set to true. I've added an angular.json snippet as requested

Comment: Seems like it's something with my Chrome. The files are displayed correctly in the firefox dev tools console